Why does Vec of slices and Vec of owned values require different lifetime parameters?
Consider the following function, recursively printing elements of a Vec:
I.
// Compiles fine
fn print_recursive_string<'a>(vec: &'a mut Vec<String>) {
    let e = vec.pop();
    if e.is_none() {
        return;
    }
    println!("{:?}", e);
    print_recursive_string(vec);
    vec.push(e.unwrap());
}

It compiles and works as expected: Rust Playground
II.
Now let's replace the element type of Vec from owned String to a slice &'a str:
// Compile error of multiple mutable borrows
fn print_recursive_slice<'a>(vec: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>) {
    let e = vec.pop();
    if e.is_none() {
        return;
    }
    println!("{:?}", e);
    print_recursive_slice(vec);
    vec.push(e.unwrap()); // <--- compile error here
}

The function refuses to compile with the following error:
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
1 | fn print_recursive_slice<'a>(vec: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>) {
  |                          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
7 |     print_recursive_slice(vec);
  |     --------------------------
  |     |                     |
  |     |                     first mutable borrow occurs here
  |     argument requires that `*vec` is borrowed for `'a`
8 |     vec.push(e.unwrap());
  |     ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

Rust Playground
III.
Now let's introduce another lifetime parameter 'b: 'a and change the element type from &'a str to &'b str:
// Magic: compiles fine
fn print_recursive_slice_lt<'a, 'b>(vec: &'a mut Vec<&'b str>)
where
    'b: 'a,
{
    let e = vec.pop();
    if e.is_none() {
        return;
    }
    println!("{:?}", e);
    print_recursive_slice_lt(vec);
    vec.push(e.unwrap());
}

This code compiles and runs fine, but it's completely unclear to me why. Rust Playground
What's wrong with making everything to be of lifetime &'a?

Just today there was another question which boiled down to the same principles: &'a mut T<'a> is always wrong.

&T can be covariant over the lifetime of T but &mut T cannot.

@cdhowie don't quite get your point. Could you please elaborate a bit?

@SomeName In &'a T<'a> the lifetime in T can be covariant with the lifetime of the reference, meaning that the lifetimes don't actually have to be the same; the compiler can shrink one of the lifetimes to match the other as long as doing so doesn't cause any borrowing issues. In &'a mut T<'a> the lifetime in T is invariant, so both of the lifetimes must exactly match. This creates an impossible situation where the data referenced by the T must live exactly as long as the mutable borrow of the T.

In particular, see this section of the nomicon.

The bound on 'b is not necessary: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22a734014b61246c54f090046a4ed460

@trueequalsfalse Both lifetimes are unnecessary.

@trueequalsfalse Why? Would it be automatically deduced to a higher lifetime?

Lifetime elision. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae11765686ab727a5245b78221519dd8.

@SomeName This should explain it (I could not find any better source unfortunately).
